# How are general quantum correlation functions actually measured?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, measurements, correlation-functions

These days, the majority of work in theoretical particle, condensed matter, and AMO physics is about methods for calculating exotic correlation functions, of the rough form
$$G_{ij} \sim \langle \mathcal{O}_i(t) \, \mathcal{O}_j(t') \rangle$$
though possibly also including time ordering, (anti)symmetrization, more operators, and so on. I'm wondering how experimentalists actually measure this quantity, to check the theorists' work.

In the trivial case where $\mathcal{O}_i(t)$ and $\mathcal{O}_j(t')$ commute (or when we can take the classical limit) an experimentalist can just measure $\mathcal{O}_i$ at time $t$, and separately $\mathcal{O}_j$ at time $t'$. But generically, they don't commute, so explicitly measuring one will affect the distribution of the other.

In quantum optics, where the $\mathcal{O}_i$ are electric field components, we can measure the first-order correlation function using interferometry: we arrange some optical setup so that the electric field coming out the other end has amplitude proportional to $E_i(\mathbf{x}_1, t) + \alpha E_j(\mathbf{x}_2, t')$ for some constant $\alpha$, and then measure that field's intensity. And we can simply measure the second-order correlation function using the click rates of separated detectors, because the number operators of different modes of the electromagnetic field commute, so the detectors don't affect each other.

It's not clear to me how the general case works. For example, consider correlation functions involving the positive and momentum of a small object, or the components of its spin. Is there a generic way such correlation functions can be measured?

Answer (score 1):

In general, you can experimentally measure generic $n$-point multitime correlation functions that can be ordered on the ["Keldysh contour"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keldysh_formalism) [see also Fig. 4 of [this work](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2208.12817.pdf)]. In principle, this just involves performing *projective measurements* of the observable $\mathcal{O}_n$ at the corresponding time $t_n$.

The measurement should be performed as quickly as possible. In general, the concern is *not* going to be that the operator fails to commute with other observables in the correlation function, since we usually probe big separations in space and time. Instead, the concern is that the observables being measured do not commute with time evolution, so the longer the measurement takes, the less accurate it is. I would argue that the two observables generically *do* commute --- we often measure $\langle A(t) A (0) \rangle$ (an autocorrealtion function of the *same* observable) and $\langle A_x (t) B_y (0) \rangle$ where $|x-y|, t \gg 1$. The time-evolved operator $A_x(t)$ may not commute with $B_y(0)$, but $[A_x,B_y]=0$ is extremely likely.

It seems like a lot of your intuition comes from optical systems, where experimentalists have developed a lot of really clever ways to measure things, and a large number of these methods involve time-dependent measurements, etc. But that is generally not the case for atomic, ionic, molecular, and solid-state systems. In those cases, the measurement is performed as quickly as possible, and usually involves coupling the system of interest to optical modes and measuring those (e.g., fluorescence state detection for atomic qubits stimulates emission and then uses standard photodetection; dispersive readout of superconducting qubits creates a shift in the frequency of the EM modes that depends on the qubit's $Z$ state, which is probed via homodyne detection of the light).

The thing you said about measuring the clicks of two separate detectors is essentially correct. We construct an interaction so that some optical modes that we control are modified according to the eigenvalue of the two observables that appear in the correlator, and the interaction is turned on at the appropriate time. Then we measure the light to learn the eigenvalue. In the case of flourescence state detection, e.g., we can improve the speed and probability of success by sending many photons, but the cost is that the system heats up. There are always tradeoffs (no free lunch theorem).

The fact that we use optical systems to implement projective measurements of nonoptical systems should give you a hint that we're much more clever when it comes to measuring optical systems. The kinds of techniques you describe for measuring things like quadratures and using interferometric tricks and sideprocessing of time-dependent signals don't have analogues outside of optical systems, as far as I know.

So for measuring position (I assume) and momentum at time 0 and $t$, respectively, you'd want $t$ to be much larger than the time it takes to measure. This is not merely a practical constraint though...if we measure position very soon after measuring momentum, the outcome will be completely random. So the correlator should vanish, on average. Such a correlator could only be nontrivial if we wait a while for the dynamics to do stuff to the collapsed state that recovers after the first measurement. Again, the measurements for correlations functions are *projective*, so it's very different from weakly coupling both the position and momentum to two separate detectors and weakly measuring both. Similar things hold for spins / qubits.

Finally, there are two things worth noting:

1. In the context of synthetic quantum systems (e.g., quantum simulators / computers), although measurements may be slow, the time evolution is usually something that has to be enforced. Meaning you can stop evolving while the measurement is implemented, and then continue thereafter. This may require dynamical decoupling of qubits or other considerations. But the point is that, in synthetic systems, you have control over the time evolution too.
2. In the context of condensed matter systems, usually you do linear response and the measurements are very well separated in both space and time. And they are extremely fast. Neutron scattering to measure spins is fast, as is running a voltage through leads and measuring resistivity, etc. Lots of experiments use imaging / scattering, which only interacts very briefly with the system. Often you simply apply a perturbation ("kick") at time 0 and make a single measurement at time $t$.

Let me know if anything above was unclear or if I misunderstood your question. Hopefully this was helpful.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful, but I think there's still something basic I'm missing. For example, for a particle in a potential, one can talk about $\langle x(t) x(0) \rangle$, and the Heisenberg operators $x(t)$ and $x(0)$ generically don't commute. You can't measure this correlation function by doing ideal projective measurements of $x$ at times $0$ and $t$, because the first such measurement will localize the particle, giving it a huge expected energy so that it just flies out of the experimental apparatus. That's why I thought the procedure couldn't involve projective measurements.

Comment: Some correlation functions may not be measurable in practice. In your example, the initial $x$ measurement should localize the particle to some position, which should be inside the apparatus given that it could be measured, although this could transfer a lot of energy to the system. Instead, you might try to prepare a particle in a position eigenstate at time $0$, then you know $x(0)$, and can do a single measurement of $x$ at time $t$ instead. And use numerous initial positions for averaging. This would probably be the preferred implementation.